# Expected Value of lowest-x-in-sample for [0,1] distribution

Tags: probability, expectation

Let's assume take N random numbers in the `[0,1]` interval. What is the expected value of the lowest number in the sample?

Running a few simulations it really seems it is

```
EV = 1/(N+1)
```

but I don't know how to prove this equation.

Farthest I went was calculating the EV for N=2 (so for two values `a` and `b`). You can easily derive that, with `a` known, EV is

```
a - (a^2)/2
```

and you just need an integral to come to the correct answer (1/3). Still, I don't know how to generalise to any N.

Comment: please use latex in your questions. for the distribution - it's easy to find the probability that the minimum will be greater than any given number $x \in [0,1]$. can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

For $x \in [0,1]$,  $P(\min\{X_1,...,X_N\} > x) = (1-x)^N$ (where here the $X_i$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and independent).

Therefore $P(Y \leq x) = 1 - (1-x)^N$, where I've denoted the min by $Y$.

$Y$ therefore has density $N(1-x)^{N-1}$ concentrated on $[0,1]$. So to calculate the expected value of $Y$ you just need to compute

$$ N\int_0^1 x(1-x)^{N-1} dx, $$

which hopefully you can do.

Comment: "... which hopefully you can do."  Hopefully, the OP will make the substitution $y = 1-x$ instead of evaluating the integral by expanding $(1-x)^{N-1}$ via the binomial theorem and then integrating term by term.

Comment: Lol, yes, hopefully...!

Comment: Hopefully, instead of computing first $P(Y\leqslant x)$ then the density of $Y$, the OP will note that $$E(Y)=\int_0^1P(Y\gt y)\mathrm dy=\int_0^1(1-y)^N\mathrm dy=\int_0^1x^N\mathrm dx=\left.\frac{x^{N+1}}{N+1}\right|_0^1=\frac1{N+1}.$$ The trick of computing the expectation from the complementary CDF is ubiquitous when the latter is simpler than the PDF, for instance as soon as minima of independent random variables are involved.